# Real time updating JavaScript variable to mysql database using node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, gruntjs

I am new to JavaScript and Node.js. I have a simple JSP page with a textbox in it. In the JavaScript I have a code to generate a random number every second and  it gets displayed in the textbox which works perfectly.

```
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
    textbox.value = y;
```

Now what I want is to store this variable in my MySQL database right when it changes using Node.js. Please tell me how I should proceed. Do I also have to use Grunt?

I have installed the node-mysql through npm already.
Thanks in advance.

P.S. I have no knowledge about Grunt. No PHP please.

Comment: how is your node server accessing the jsp page?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You have a JavaServer Page or a Node server with MySQL?

Also, Grunt is a task runner and would not be needed for this. Grunt would help you minify your javascript, or bundle your app for production, or compile your sass to css.

Comment: I haven't written any code for node yet. And it is a JavaServer page. Can I do it using AJAX?

Comment: I would recommend taking a step back and doing some research and understanding what role each part plays. You would need to setup a node server with MySQL and then yes, make AJAX requests to POST that data to your server. On your server you'd have some code running to receive that POST and then store the data in your database. 

I'm not sure exactly how JSP works (didn't know people still used it), but I'm assuming it serves javascript you've written to be ran in the browser. This is where you would make the AJAX requests.

Comment: @steezeburger That worked! Thank you. Cheers mate!